# How to call Extjs app from outside app directory

Tags: extjs, zend-framework2, extjs6

I have generate app using Sencha cmd in zend framework in `public/js/app` folder
now i want to load the application for Layout folder i have included the `bootstrap.js` file `layout.phtml` but it is not loading the **app**
also if i **`build the app using Sencha app build`** how will i access the build app within the `layout.phtml`

Comment: You need to access the app.js file, from there the app starting. look if all reference to js and css files are correct.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to call **Extjs 6 app** is to call the `bootstrap.js` file from any where and bring the `App.json` file into the directory where you are calling the app

`app.json` and `classic.json` and `modern.json` have all the paths